# Encoding.Convert Unicode to code page 864

Tags: c#, encoding, arabic

I am trying use the `Encoding.Convert` method in C# to convert a string from encoding 1256 to 864 (both Arabic) using the following code.

```
    static void example()
    {
        string unicodeString = "ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي";
        // Create two different encodings.
        Encoding cp1256 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

        // Convert the string into a byte array. 
        byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

        // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other. 
        byte[] cp1256Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, cp1256, unicodeBytes);
        //                              ^
        //                              |
        //                           Above convert works

        Encoding cp864 = Encoding.GetEncoding(864);
        byte[] cp864bytes = Encoding.Convert(cp1256, cp864, cp1256Bytes);
        //Above convert does not work and it returns an array of ?

        string cp864String = cp864.GetString(cp864bytes);

        // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString);
        Console.WriteLine("CP864 converted string: {0}", cp864String);

    }
```

The conversion from UNICODE to 1256 works fine, I get all the characters, however, when I convert from 1256 to 864, I get the question mark characters (?).

Any suggestions please.

Comment: You have to convert the Unicode codepoints to Presentation Form B first.  The Unicode codepoints that represent the different forms of the letters, distinguishing between the initial, medial, final, isolated shapes of the letters.  As would have been necessary back in the MS-Dos days, no smart text renderer back then that could figure it out by itself.  Might be tough, I don't see a wholeheckofalot of library support for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this one from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fba83600-7d45-46df-bbaa-21658f048676/a-problem-in-encoding-in-cp-864)

> Maybe `Encoding.GetEncoding(864).GetBytes` is not supported by
>   Operating System. But you can implement your own conversion from
>   characters to bytes using this table:
>
> http://www.ascii.ca/cp864.htm.